# Write a String to filename in c

Tags: c

I have this code and can´t get it properly to work. I want to write the String Output into a file.

```
static void wr_message_user_info_login(wi_p7_message_t *message) {
    wi_date_t           *date;
    wi_string_t         *string, *interval;
    wi_p7_uint32_t      uid, build, bits;

    wr_printf_block(WI_STR("Login: %@"),
        wi_p7_message_string_for_name(message, WI_STR("wired.user.login")));

    char *filename = "/.wirebot/wirebot.login";
    char *home_dir = getenv("HOME");
    char *filepath = malloc(strlen(home_dir) + strlen(filename) + 1);
    sprintf(filepath, "%s%s", home_dir, filename);

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(filepath, "w");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
    }
    else
    {
        fputs((WI_STR("Login: %@")), fp);
);
        fclose(fp);
    }
```

"Login: %@" should be writed to file. Echoing is working fine.

Comment: `"/.wirebot/wirebot.login"` should probably be `"./wirebot/wirebot.login"` to indicate relative directory?

Comment: "Can't get it properly to work". What "works" and what does not? What is the unbalanced `);` in the code?

Comment: `char *filepath = malloc(strlen(home_dir) + strlen(filename) + 1);` may have issues unless all terminating directory delimiters ( `/`) are included in length.

Comment: Have you checked the values of `filename`, `homedir` and `filepath`? For example by printing them to the console. Are they all correct?

Comment: Don't forget to `free` what you `malloc`, by the way.

Comment: Yes, they are correct.

Comment: And what is `WI_STR`? What does it do? What library are you using with all those `wi_` or `WI_` prefixes for functions, macros and types? Please [edit] your question to include a [mre], as well as the actual behavior.

Comment: And when you [edit] your question to give us more details, also please include debugging output of `filepath` in your [mre], and tell us its value. And also please tell us the right you have to write to the `~/.wirebot` directory.

Comment: Its from here:
https://github.com/ProfDrLuigi/wirebot/blob/master/wirebot/messages.c

The Problem is I try to "Maintain" this project because developer discontinued it. I'm bad in C (Swift is my way normally). Now I try it with trial and Error. I have those file writes already 3 times on another place in the project and it works well there. The only thing here is to know how I must format the string output. For me C is very confusing somehow.

Here is one working for example:
https://github.com/ProfDrLuigi/wirebot/blob/master/wirebot/windows.c
Line 423

Comment: You should start off by dedicating a little time to looking at a good C book.  Become familiar with it at least enough to use as a reference source to navigate  the issues you come up with regarding differences between the syntax between the two languages.

Comment: I do not know what `wr_printf_block(...)` is.  Is it is defined in your code somewhere? Or is it in a library?

Comment: You are wasting  time if you don't implement proper error handling.  If now on this problem then the next.

Answer (score 0):

You provided a snippet of code with a lot of stuff missing.  If you strip the stuff you haven't told us about it seems to work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static void wr_message_user_info_login() {
    const char *filename = "/.wirebot/wirebot.login";
    const char *home_dir = getenv("HOME");
    char *filepath = malloc(strlen(home_dir) + strlen(filename) + 1);
    if(!filepath) {
        printf("malloc failed\n");
        return;
    }
    sprintf(filepath, "%s%s", home_dir, filename);
    FILE *fp = fopen(filepath, "w");
    if (!fp) {
        printf("fopen failed\n");
        free(filepath);
        return;
    }
    free(filepath);
    fputs("Login: %@", fp);
    fclose(fp);
}

int main() {
    wr_message_user_info_login();
}
```

and example run:

```
$ mkdir ~/.wirebot && ./a.out && cat ~/.wirebot/wirebot.login
Login: %@
```

Maybe the directory ~/.wirebot doesn't exist on your host?